# Is there a word for 'a person who thinks or feels that they are younger than their age'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am not talking about autism. My question is about a normal person.

Comment: You mean they're simply innumerate?

Comment: "Young in mind" or "eternal adolescent" ?

Comment: "[Young at heart](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/young+at+heart)"?

Comment: I'd like to ask if this person simply thinks/feel like being younger (whilst not being so in actuality), or are they *actually* like that? Depending on the answer, the words will differ.

Comment: It's my personal experience that anyone healthy and moderately attractive, and  over the age of 40, "feels" younger than their actual years. It's what you have to keep telling yourself!

Comment: The person is a _Peter Pan_.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to them as ***delusional***. (Ha-ha)

> having false or unrealistic beliefs or opinions

Jokes aside though, the words that can be suitable are perhaps ***neanimorphic***

> looking younger than one's years

or ***agerasia***

> youthful appearance in an old person

Answer (score 0):

**childlike**

> (of an adult) having good qualities associated with a child: *she speaks with a childlike directness*.